# Adding liquid schema settings to string

Tags: arrays, string, shopify, liquid

I have 4 schema settings set up for a section and trying to figure out how to assign them to a string and then use split to create an array because I want to loop through them to create 4 HTML code blocks instead of hard coding each HTML code block. I want to be able to access each settings object like .id, .title, etc..

```
{% assign recent_articles_string = "{{section.settings.article_one}},{{section.settings.article_two}},{{section.settings.article_three}},{{section.settings.article_alt}}" %}

{% assign recent_articles_array = recent_articles_string | split: ',' %}

{% for recent_article in recent_articles_array %}
{%- comment -%} HTML code block {%- endcomment -%}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried trouble shooting and did a search on here but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally following what you are trying to do but you cannot nest a liquid output statement {{ }} inside a liquid logic and control flow statement {% %}.
Probably best to use a capture tag instead.

```
{% capture recent_articles_string %} 
  {{section.settings.article_one}},
  {{section.settings.article_two}},
  {{section.settings.article_three}},
  {{section.settings.article_alt }}
{% endcapture %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am trying to create a suggested "read more" sidebar for the article page and I want to find a way to loop over the 4 `{{section.settings.article}}`s  to be used in dynamic HTML  instead of repeating myself 4 times for the HTML to be displayed.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, I would categorise the articles with tags and then loop through the articles with the same tag excluding the page you are on and display articles like that.